# How do I check if a variable is defined in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

```
<% if dashboard_pane_counter.remainder(3) == 0 %>
  do something
<% end>
```

If dasboard_pane_counter wasn't defined, how can I get this to evaluate to false rather than throw an exception?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

```
<% if defined?(:dashboard_pane_counter) && dashboard_pane_counter.remainder(3) == 0  %>
  # do_something here, this assumes that dashboard_pane_counter is defined, but not nil
<% end %>
```

Comment: symbol did not work for me. so i had to check this way `if defined?(variable_name)`

Answer (score 5):

When using rails and instance variables, nil has a `try` method defined, so you can do:

```
<% if @dashboard_pane_counter.try(:remainder(3)) == 0  %>
   #do something
<% end %>
```

so if the instance variable is not defined, `try(:anything)` will return nil and therefore evaluate to false. And `nil == 0` is false

Comment: This will still cause an error if the variable hasn't been defined, so doesn't answer the question.

Comment: No it won't, rails has 'magic built in':
`1.9.3p392 :005 > @hh
 => nil 
1.9.3p392 :006 > @hh.try(:anything)
 => nil `

Comment: So for instance variables, nil has a 'try' method

Comment: Ah, you're right, my mistake. If you edit your answer to that clear I can remove my down vote.

Answer (score 5):

local_assigns can be used for that, since this question is from a few years ago, I verified that it exists in previous versions of rails

```
<% if local_assigns[:dashboard_pane_counter] 
                 && dashboard_pane_counter.remainder(3) == 0%>
<% end %>
```

It's in the notes here

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render

Answer (score 0):

Posting this answer for beginner coders like myself. This question can be answered simply using two steps (or one if using &&). It is a longer and less pretty answer but helps new coders to understand what they are doing and uses a very simple technique that is not present in any of the other answers yet. The trick is to use an instance (@) variable, it will not work with a local variable:

```
if @foo
  "bar"
end
```

If @foo is defined it will be return "bar", otherwise not (with no error). Therefore in two steps:

```
if @dashboard_pane_counter
  if @dashboard_plane_counter.remainder(3) == 0
    do something
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Another way, with a neat gem, is 'andand.'

https://github.com/raganwald/andand

Answer (score -3):

Insted of

```
if !var.nil?
```

I would use

```
unless var.nil?
```

Thats much better ruby code!

Comment: this only applies if the variable was defined previous to this code.  Try if !adallajglaksdkfaj.nil? on the first line of a "function".  kablammo :)